# Updating country name in magento 2

Tags: magento2, country-regions, directory

I need to change the name of country in magento store e.g. `United Kingdom` needs to be changed to `Great Britain`. How can I achieve this?

I tried looking at the following tables `directory_country_region`, `directory_country_region_name`, `directory_country` but country full names are not stored here.

I also tried using locale files to see if it updates, but no luck there as well.

Is there any way I can achieve this?

Comment: I have added the answer !

Comment: @prateek did you solve this issue, if yes please update the answer

Comment: @prateek Did you solve? If can please share with me. I got same issue.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way for changing the label is by translation.

You need to just make i18N folder in your app/code/namespace/modulename/i18n and just create one CSV file en_US.csv and give translation script over there.

```
See Example : en_US.csv

"United Kingdom","Great Britain"
```

No need to do anything for the small change.

Comment: That did not work, I guess because country is fetched from product attributes and translation is not applied there. But I also need the product searched by country name so just changing the locale won't cut it. I need to change the country name from source.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where exactly you'd want to change the country name, but the country names in Magento come from the Zend framework.

In Zend they are stored in locale file, for example in

> /vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Locale/Data/en_GB.xml

```
<territories>
    <territory type="GB">United Kingdom</territory>
    <territory type="GB" alt="short">UK</territory>
    <territory type="GS">South Georgia and the South Sandwich Islands</territory>
    <territory type="HM">Heard Island and McDonald Islands</territory>
    <territory type="UM">U.S. Minor Outlying Islands</territory>
    <territory type="US">United States</territory>
    <territory type="US" alt="short">US</territory>
    <territory type="VC">Saint Vincent and the Grenadines</territory>
</territories>
```

Comment: Although it is not recommended to change files in the vendor folder, I still tried it, in en.xml and en_GB.xml,  cleared my cache, but that did not work either. I'm still getting United Kingdom.

Comment: @Prateek which locale are you using? Maybe you have to edit the en_US.xml. Don't forget to clear all the cache, i.e. delete `var/cache` or clear Redis as it's not stored in one of the usual caches.

Comment: @AndreasvonStudnitz I have en_GB as my locale, I did clear var/cache too but no use

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue (Magento 2.3.5-p1) and I fixed it by updating the translation file of my theme.

Go to app/design/frontend/YOURTHEME/YOURTHEME/i18n

if your locale language is English (US), you will have a en_US.csv file in it. Then add a line with:
United Kingdom, Great Britain

For other languages, do the same in the other csv files or create them if they don't alrady exist.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue and solved by following steps:

1. edit [TranslatedListsTest.php](https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/24179/files) in lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Locale/Test/Unit/
2. edit [TranslatedLists.php](https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/24179/files) in lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Locale/
3. make i18N folder in your app/design/frontend/[theme]/ and create en_US.CSV file if your language is en_US

> "United Kingdom","Great Britain"

4. clean all the cache by commend:

   php bin/magento s:up

   php bin/magento s:s:d

   php bin/magento c:f
5. Complete to translate

Hope it's work for you.