# Magento 2.2.4 Change Country Names

Tags: localisation, locale, country-regions

I am wanting to change the names in English for countries in Magento 2.2.4. I tried looking through the database but it appears their full name is not listed there, just country codes.  For my use of magento, only a few countries need to remain and they all need to be renamed.  This site will not be used for shipping items, it is for internal use.

For the sake of an example change, Japan could be changed to Nippon.

I have found the following questions:
[Updating country name in magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/223609/updating-country-name-in-magento-2)
and
[How to Get country name from country code in Magento 2?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/159494/how-to-get-country-name-from-country-code-in-magento-2)

Both of them mention editing a *.csv file in an i18N folder.  One says editing one within a module and another doesn't specify.  I did find such a folder in: `/Magento/lib/web/i18n/en_US.csv` but adding 'Japan','Nippon' to that file didn't work as I assume it only applies to those web error messages.

I also came across this: [How to add new country in country dropdown in magento2.2.1](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/217530/how-to-add-new-country-in-country-dropdown-in-magento2-2-1?rq=1)

I couldn't find the folder described there but I did find `/Magento/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Locale/Data/en.xml` which I edited the territory name, flushed the caches and found nothing had changed.

Can anyone assist?

Answer (score 0):

The way I have done is via CPanel. I log into my CPanel account

> (www.yourwebsitename.com/cpanel) >> public folder >> app >> locale >>
>   translations.

Then, you shall create a folder for the desired translation; something like **jp_JP**. **Create/upload** a .**csv** file with the original languade between " " followed by a ; symbol and the word in Japanese, between " ".

From this way, the translations will run accordingly if you change the languages.

Comment: Sorry, I am running this on a private server so I don't have CPanel installed.  I don't have any folders like the one you described.